# Basic Prolog Family Relation

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and was hoping someone could clear this up for me.  I want to query if someone is a father.  So I wrote the following statements and rules:

```
man(Joe).
man(Josh).
man(John).

parent(Joe,Josh).
parent(Josh,John).

father(D,K) :- man(D), parent(D,K).
```

I am confused because when I run the query:

```
father(Joe,John).
true.
```

It returns true.  Why is this?  It seems to be searching though the relations but I have no idea why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prolog, strings that start with a capital are variables. When you write `parent(Joe,Josh).`, you're not defining a relationship between two people Joe and Josh, but you're saying that the parent relationship is true for any values of the variables 'Joe' and 'Josh'.

For the relations to work as expected, you have to either use lower-case atoms (e.g. `father(joe,josh).`), or use quoted atoms (`father('Joe', 'Josh').`).